# Pyspark regex to data frame

Tags: pyspark

I have a code similar to this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

def regex_filter(x):
    regexs = ['.*123.*']

    if x and x.strip():
        for r in regexs:
            if re.match(r, x, re.IGNORECASE):
                return True

    return False 


filter_udf = udf(regex_filter, BooleanType())

df_filtered = df.filter(filter_udf(df.fieldXX))
```

I want to use "regexs" var to verify if any digit "123" is in "fieldXX"

i don't know what i did wrong!
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: We can't tell what you did wrong unless we have some sample input and output. Are you getting an error? The wrong answer? Read [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) and try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is incorrect.

I think it should be something like:

`regexs = '.*[123].*'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL function to attain this

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_temp")
df_1 = spark.sql("select *, case when col1 like '%123%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end col2 from df_temp")
```

Disadvantage in using UDF is you cannot save the data frame back or do any manipulations in that data frame further.

Comment: *Disadvantage in using UDF is you cannot save the data frame back or do any manipulations in that data frame further.*? Would you care to clarify that statement?

Comment: After using UDF you are taking the result in a data frame df_1, you cannot save it back to HDFS or you cannot use df_1 to do further manipulation, it will through error

Comment: That is absolutely not true. Please show me some documentation to support this claim.

Comment: I experienced this when I am using UDF, you can try for yourself